# cor() function giving unexpected result for numeric data frame(Updated)

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I have a file named "specdata" which has a lot of CSV that each have the columns: ("Date", "sulfate", "nitrate", "ID"). I want to calculate the correlation between nitrate and sulfate, and I am using the cor() function from the stats package for this. The expected result looks different from mine and I don't know why.

If anyone has passed the [R Programming course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/r-programming?), the question is from the programming assignment from week 2

```
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
corr <- function(directory, threshold=0){
  csvFiles <-  getFilesById(directory)
  dataFrames <-  readMultipleCsvFiles(csvFiles)
  noNADataFrames <- lapply(dataFrames, na.omit)
  acceptableDataFrames <- filterMoreThanThreshold(noNADataFrames, threshold)
  correlation(acceptableDataFrames)
}
getFilesById <- function(directory = getwd()){
  allFiles = list.files(directory)
  file.path(directory, allFiles)
}
readMultipleCsvFiles <- function(csvFiles) {
  lapply(csvFiles, read.csv)
}
filterMoreThanThreshold <- function(noNADataFrames, threshold){
  Filter(function(x){NROW(x)>threshold}, noNADataFrames)
}
bindMultipleDataFrames <- function(dataFrames) {
  Reduce(function(x, y) rbind(x, y), dataFrames)
}
correlation <- function(acceptableDataFrames){
  sulfate <- lapply(acceptableDataFrames, function(x){x[2]})
  sulfate <- bindMultipleDataFrames(sulfate)
  nitrate <- lapply(acceptableDataFrames, function(x){x[3]})
  nitrate <- bindMultipleDataFrames(nitrate)
  sulnit <-  cbind(sulfate, nitrate)
  cor(sulnit)
}
cr <- corr("specdata", 150)
head(cr)
summary(cr)
```

I'm supposed to get this:

```
 > head(cr)
 [1] -0.01895754 -0.14051254 -0.04389737 -0.06815956 -0.12350667 -0.07588814
     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 > summary(cr)
 -0.21057 -0.04999  0.09463  0.12525  0.26844  0.76313
```

But instead I get this:

```
> head(cr)
           sulfate    nitrate
sulfate 1.00000000 0.06088486
nitrate 0.06088486 1.00000000
> summary(cr)
    sulfate           nitrate       
 Min.   :0.06088   Min.   :0.06088  
 1st Qu.:0.29566   1st Qu.:0.29566  
 Median :0.53044   Median :0.53044  
 Mean   :0.53044   Mean   :0.53044  
 3rd Qu.:0.76522   3rd Qu.:0.76522  
 Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.00000
```

Comment: So, I'd unpack my functions to get started and get a sense of whether I'm getting more than one file, or one value. What does `length(acceptableDataFrames)` or `length(cr)` say you've got?

Comment: length(acceptableDataFrames) gives me 234 and length(cr) gives me 1. class(cr) gives me numeric.